# How ApplicationBuilder set 404 status code in a RequestDelegate?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Builder/ApplicationBuilder.cs,132

```
public class ApplicationBuilder : IApplicationBuilder {

   private readonly List<Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>> _components = new();
   ...
   public IApplicationBuilder Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware) {   
      _components.Add(middleware);
      return this;
   }

   public RequestDelegate Build() {
      RequestDelegate app = context => {  
         ...
         context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
         return Task.CompletedTask;
      }
   }

   for (var c = _components.Count - 1; c >= 0; c--) { 
      app = _components[c](app);
   }
   return app;
}
```

As you can see, the RequestDelegate `app` will always be executed, which means the status code will be set to 404, which doesn't make sense at all. For me, the code should be sth like:

```
public RequestDelegate Build() {
   RequestDelegate app = context => {
      ...
      if (context.Response has not been set) {  // pesudo code
         context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
      }      
      return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
}
```

For example, let's say we have the following code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
   app.UseRouting();
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
      endpoints.MapGet("routing", async context => {
         await context.Response.WriteAsync("Request Was Routed");
      });
   });

   app.Use(async (context, next) => { // let's call it terminal middleware
      await context.Response.WriteAsync("Terminal Middleware Reached");
   });
}
```

You can see that the terminal middleware is the last middleware to execute and write the response but according to the ApplicationBuilder source code, the status coded will still be set to 404, which doesn't make sense at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code assumes that you have already added the endpoint middleware: https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/EndpointMiddleware.cs

```
// If we reach the end of the pipeline, but we have an endpoint, then something unexpected has happened.
// This could happen if user code sets an endpoint, but they forgot to add the UseEndpoint middleware.
```

In the endpoint middleware:

```
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var endpoint = httpContext.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint;
            if (endpoint?.RequestDelegate != null)
            {
                Log.ExecutingEndpoint(_logger, endpoint);

               try
                {
                    await endpoint.RequestDelegate(httpContext);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Log.ExecutedEndpoint(_logger, endpoint);
                }
                return;
            }

            await _next(httpContext);
        }
```

So the code you shared, handled the non existence of an endpoint, thus returning 404.

Comment: thanks for your answering, I just edited the question and provide an concrete example, could you have a second look because the applicationbuilder source code still doesn't make sense to me.